# Query string in URL in Power Apps

Tags: regex, powerapps, utm, powerapps-canvas

I'm creating a UTM generator in Power apps. I have to remove the query string (utm_source, utm_medium and utm_campaign) from the URL that user can paste to the URL input. Also, I have to keep the rest on the valuse like utm_test

For example - from URL:
[www.testpage.html?utm_source=empsig_12&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=aw_e_be+dk_agc_test&utm_test=test](http://www.testpage.html?utm_source=empsig_12&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=aw_e_be+dk_agc_test&utm_test=test)

I want to get URL like this:

[www.testpage.html?utm_test=test](http://www.testpage.html?utm_test=test)

For now I have something like this:

`Match(txt_URL.Text, "(utm_source)=([^&#]*&?)|(utm_medium)=([^&#]*&?)|(utm_campaign)=([^&#]*&?)").FullMatch`

but it returns only the first match - `utm_source=empsig_12&`

thanks in advance

Comment: Use `MatchAll(txt_URL.Text, "(utm_(?:campaign|source|medium))=([^&#]*&?)")`

Comment: Works fine thanks! But how can I convert it to the string like - `utm_source=empsig_12&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=aw_e_be+dk_agc_test&`

Comment: got it, thank you very much! `Concat(MatchAll(txt_URL.Text, "(utm_(?:campaign|source|medium))=([^&#]*&?)"), FullMatch, "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`MatchAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-ismatch) and then [`Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-concatenate) the matches:

```
Concat(
  MatchAll(txt_URL.Text, "(utm_(?:campaign|source|medium))=([^&#]*&?)"), 
  FullMatch, 
  ""
)
```

The regex matches

- `(utm_(?:campaign|source|medium))` - Group 1: `utm_` and then either `campaign`, `source` or `medium`
- `=` - a `=` char
- `([^&#]*&?)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than `&` and `#` and then an optional `&`.